# How to get the hour and minutes in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to get and display the date, hours and minutes separately (3 columns: date, hours and minutes)

My script doesn't work. How to fix this? Thank you

Here's the sql:

```
 select trunc(t.create_time, 'DD') as createdate
            ,trunc(t.close_time, 'DD') as closedate
            ,datepart(hour, t.close_time()) as hours
            ,datepart(minute, t.close_time()) as minutes
            ,count(t.close_time) as total
      from app_account.otrs_ticket t
      left join app_account.otrs_user u
      on t.create_user_id=u.id
      where u.id not in (15,7,31,49,50,52,62,66,69,106,17,24,44,32,33,55,22,29,30,47,45,53,70,74,109,1,2,10,23,68,80,20,21,56,108,67)
      group by trunc(t.create_time, 'DD')
              ,trunc(t.close_time, 'DD')
              ,datepart(hour, t.close_time())
              ,datepart(minute, t.close_time())
      order by trunc(t.create_time, 'DD') desc
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I find the `to_char()` function to be the most flexible for converting and extracting date parts.

Here is an example that extracts the various elements from sysdate:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY') as year, 
       to_char(sysdate, 'MM') as month, 
       to_char(sysdate, 'DD') as day,
       to_char(sysdate, 'HH24') as hour,
       to_char(sysdate, 'MI') as minute
from dual
```

You can supply different format parameters to get whatever result you require.

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle functions are `extract()` or `to_char()`:

```
 select trunc(t.create_time, 'DD') as createdate,
        trunc(t.close_time, 'DD') as closedate,
        extract(hour from t.close_time) as hours,
        extract(minute from t.close_time) as minutes,
        count(t.close_time) as total
 from app_account.otrs_ticket t left join
      app_account.otrs_user u
      on t.create_user_id=u.id
 where u.id not in (15,7,31,49,50,52,62,66,69,106,17,24,44,32,33,55,22,29,30,47,45,53,70,74,109,1,2,10,23,68,80,20,21,56,108,67)
 group by trunc(t.create_time, 'DD'), trunc(t.close_time, 'DD')
          extract(hour from t.close_time) as hours,
          extract(minute from t.close_time) as minutes
 order by trunc(t.create_time, 'DD') desc;
```

I'm not sure what the `()` are after `close_time`, but they don't seem necessary.

Comment: I test your script and i get an error: ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source
30076. 00000 -  "invalid extract field for extract source"
*Cause:    The extract source does not contain the specified extract field.

Comment: These functions have been available in Oracle for a while:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm.

Comment: Is it possible that `t.close_time` is not a date/time value?

Comment: No. close_time is always date/time hmm

Comment: `EXTRACT` works only for `TIMESTAMP` and `INTERVAL` data types, not on `DATE` types.

Comment: @Wernfried . . . Check the documentation.  The *examples* in the documentation use `date` (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm).

Comment: @GordonLinoff Well, from a `DATE` value you can extrat only `YEAR`, `MONTH` and `DAY`. `HOUR` or `MINUTE` does not work.