# Oracle SQL: condition for a specific date format

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a date column which usually constists of data + hour + minutes.
Sometimes it's just a date.
I want to make a condition in where clause, to fetch records only if they have data, hour and minute.
How can I do that?

Comment: Apparently you can use `to_char()` or `extract()` to get the DateTime parts Hour or Minute in Oracle and then check whether those are `> 0` see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26644466/how-to-get-the-hour-and-minutes-in-oracle-sql

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, a `DATE` data type is a binary data type consisting of 7 bytes that represent: century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second. It **ALWAYS** has those 7 bytes and it is **NEVER** stored in any particular (human-readable) format.

Given this, your question does not make sense as you cannot have a `DATE` data type that does not have hour, minute or second components. If the time components are not provided then default values will be used and set the hours, minutes and/or seconds to 0.

If we rephrase the question to:

> I want to make a condition in where clause, to fetch records only if the time component of the date is not midnight. How can I do that?

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  date_column > TRUNC(date_column);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The point of my query is to find workers who work after work hours. So, currentlly it's hard for me to tell if midnight appears because it is a deafault, or is it because of the employee. If I understood you correctly, the default version will always be 00:00:00 and not for example 00:00:03? Cause I seem to get a lot of 00:00:XX and 00:15:XX.

Comment: @Alex If you use `TO_DATE('1970-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')` or `TO_DATE('1970-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` then they will both generate a date `1970-01-01 00:00:00` and there is no way to tell that one had default values for the time and one was explicitly specified. If you have the time `HH:MM:SS` and the values are non-zero then they cannot have been the default values.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thanks, that is what I'd intended to write. I'd not spotted the the extra `=` that my fingers had snuck in.